# Triggering 2 java programs using batch script (windows) : multiple queries

Tags: java, batch-file

**Query 1**
I have 2 separate java programs. 
- MasterProgram.java - Runs for long time due to high data
- MailProgram.java - Used for sending log file via mail for every 30 minutes 
I use single batchScript program to trigger these 2 java programs.

My requirement is,,
 Until "MasterProgram.java" gets completed, for every 30 minutes "MailProgram.java" has to run and Once "MasterProgram.java" gets completed "MailProgram.java" has to run. 
Any idea's/alternative solutions to implement the logic is appreciated.

**Query 2 (not related to above query):** 
i trigger 2 java programs asynchronously using batch script.

```
myprogram.bat

@ECHO OFF
start /b java Mainprogram    :: program1
start /b java MainprogramAnother    :: program2
```

is it possible to echo the %ERRORLEVEL% of **programs** as shown below ?

```
myprogram.bat
@ECHO OFF
start /b java Mainprogram    :: program1
start /b java MainprogramAnother    :: program2

echo "Program1 errorlevel"
:: i am aware that below will not print program1 status. 
:: Can you suggest the right code to display %ERRORLEVEL% this way..
echo %ERRORLEVEL%   
echo "Program2 errorlevel"
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

if any alternate ways are present please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is a pretty dodgy solution but why don't you give it a go to see if it works:

#### Main.bat

```
@echo off
start Side.bat
java MasterProgram.java  
start java MailProgram.java
start taskkill /f /im cmd.exe
```

#### Side.bat

```
@echo off
:: Make sure 'MasterProgram.java' has properly started
sleep 5
:loop
start java MailProgram.java
sleep 1800
:: 1800 seconds = 30 minutes
goto loop
```

**`Main.bat`** starts **`side.bat`** and waits for `MasterProgram.java` to execute before running the `MailProgram.java`. It ends by killing all instances of `cmd.exe`.

**`Side.bat`** runs `MailProgram.java` every 30 minutes until it is `taskkilled` by `Main.bat`.

It should work for you.

As for your second question, just store it in variables.

```
@ECHO OFF
start /b java Mainprogram    :: program1
set p1=%ERRORLEVEL% 
start /b java MainprogramAnother    :: program2
set p2=%ERRORLEVEL% 

echo "Program1 errorlevel"
echo %p1%  
echo "Program2 errorlevel"
echo %p2%
```

Comment: Thanks for ur time.. for 2nd query, printing with variable is ok. but as the program runs asynchronously, the error level gets printed before the program gets completed. So am not getting the error level am expecting (in asynchronous process).. i need to initiate an asynchronous process and its child process dependent on it must execute in a synchronized manner , one by one..

Comment: like a callback function

Comment: in the soln you gave for query 1 ,, is it possible to kill the first asynchronous process which calls "side.bat" at once when the synchronous process java MasterProgram.java  gets completed?